# jQuery loading wrong values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using some sliders that were part of bootstrap theme I purchased. I am not very good with jQuery and I need help to make this load properly.  It is pulling the initial value from some php code earlier in the file which works fine, but the problem is on the initial load it puts the value in '$("#mechanicalCondition").val()' into all three hidden inputs for mechanicalCondtion, interiorCondtion, and exteriorCondition.  If I move the sliders, they correct themselves. I am pretty sure I need to create a unique name instead of using 'this' but I don't know how to do it in jQuery.  Thanks in advance.
 **Here is the script.**

```
<script>
    $("#slider-example > span").each(function() {
        var value;
        value = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
        return $(this).empty().slider({
          value: value,
          range: "min",
          animate: true,
          orientation: "vertical"
        });
    });

    $("#slider-example1").slider({
        value: <?=$mechanical?>,
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          $("#mechanicalCondition").val(ui.value);
          return $("#slider-example1-amount").text(ui.value + " stars");
        }
     });

     $("#slider-example1-amount").text($("#slider-example1").slider("value") + " stars" );
     $("#mechanicalCondition").val($("#slider-example1").slider("value") );

    $("#slider-example2").slider({
        value: <?=$interior?>,
            min: 1,
            max: 10,
            step: 1,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
              $("#interiorCondition").val(ui.value);
              return $("#slider-example2-amount").text(ui.value + " stars");
            }
      });

    $("#slider-example2-amount").text($("#slider-example1").slider("value") + " stars");
    $("#interiorCondition").val($("#slider-example1").slider("value") );

    $("#slider-example3").slider({
        value: <?=$exterior?>,
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#exteriorCondition").val(ui.value);
            return $("#slider-example3-amount").text(ui.value + " stars");
        }
      });

      $("#slider-example3-amount").text($("#slider-example1").slider("value") + " stars");
      $("#exteriorCondition").val($("#slider-example1").slider("value") );
```

**Here is the php section.**

```
 <div class='form-group'>
  <strong>Mechanical Condition</strong>
    <div class='text-right'>
        <small id='slider-example1-amount'></small>
        <input type="hidden" id="mechanicalCondition" name="mechanicalCondition" value="">
    </div>
    <div id='slider-example1' style='margin-bottom: 20px; clear: both;'>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class='form-group'>
    <strong>Interior Condition</strong>
       <div class='text-right'>
          <small id='slider-example2-amount'></small>
          <input type="hidden" id="interiorCondition" name="interiorCondition" value="">
       </div>
      <div id='slider-example2' style='margin-bottom: 20px; clear: both;'>    
      </div>
 </div>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <strong>Exterior Condition</strong>
    <div class='text-right'>
        <small id='slider-example3-amount'></small>
        <input type="hidden" id="exteriorCondition" name="exteriorCondition" value="">
    </div>
    <div id='slider-example3' style='margin-bottom: 20px; clear: both;'>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
$("#slider-example2-amount").text($("#slider-example1").slider("value") + " stars");
$("#interiorCondition").val($("#slider-example1").slider("value") );
```

To:

```
$("#slider-example2-amount").text($("#slider-example2").slider("value") + " stars");
$("#interiorCondition").val($("#slider-example2").slider("value") );
```

and

```
$("#slider-example3-amount").text($("#slider-example1").slider("value") + " stars");
$("#exteriorCondition").val($("#slider-example1").slider("value") );
```

To:

```
$("#slider-example3-amount").text($("#slider-example3").slider("value") + " stars");
$("#exteriorCondition").val($("#slider-example3").slider("value") );
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try that.  Must have been staring at the screen too long.  Thank you.  That fixed it.